# Using product flavors; How to remove one version of an app automatically?

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-version

I am able to make two versions of an app using product flavours but how to delete the 'lite' version when the 'pro' version is installed? Can this be done without the use of a library project?

Comment: Have you read this? https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#product-flavors

Comment: @josemigallas - i have refered to that link